# "SSL certificate verify failed" using pip to install packages

Tags: python, macos, ssl, pip

I am trying to install the Scrapy package (among others) for python using pip. I have tried doing the installation using python 3 and python 2, I have installed/upgraded the setuptools like so: `$ pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`, I have tried to use the `--trusted-host` option like so: `$ pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.python.org Scrapy`. But I always get the same error message when I run `$ pip3 install Scrapy`. The complete output is this:

```
Collecting Scrapy
  Using cached Scrapy-1.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz
Collecting service-identity (from Scrapy)
  Using cached service_identity-16.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from Scrapy)
  Using cached pyOpenSSL-16.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting w3lib>=1.15.0 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached w3lib-1.17.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting parsel>=1.1 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached parsel-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting queuelib (from Scrapy)
  Using cached queuelib-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Scrapy)
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from Scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-17.1.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/incremental/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    Couldn't find index page for 'incremental' (maybe misspelled?)
    Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:749) -- Some packages may not be found!
    No local packages or working download links found for incremental>=16.10.1
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/gy/5xt04_452z791v1qjs1yzxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-nkv4jozy/Twisted/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**_setup["getSetupArgs"]())
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 108, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 317, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 372, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1123, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1135, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 440, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 668, in easy_install
        raise DistutilsError(msg)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('incremental>=16.10.1')

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gy/5xt04_452z791v1qjs1yzxkh0000gn/T/pip-build-nkv4jozy/Twisted/
```

I am on a mac OS version 10.12.1 and am using python 3.6.
Does anybody know a solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you behind a corporate firewall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip install fails with "connection error: \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed (\_ssl.c:598)"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi) <-- see Kernobs answer here ... it gives a whole bunch of options any of which might work.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr , no I am not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated here https://bugs.python.org/issue28150 in previous versions of python Apple supplied the OpenSSL packages but does not anymore.

Running the command `pip install certifi` and then `pip install Scrapy` fixed it for me

Comment: also possible to install OpenSSL via brew (or whatever package manager). on some Linux systems, you also may need to install ca-certificates (or whatever variation of that your distro has, but that's usually the correct name)

Answer (score 15):

**`pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org autopep8 (any package name)`**

This command will add `pypi.python.org` to the trusted sources and will install all the required package.

I ran into the error myself and typing this command helped me install all the pip packages of python.

Comment: it should be noted that this is a VERY RISKY IDEA! this disables HTTPS certificate validation, and allows a man in the middle to install ARBITRARY CODE. curl calls this option --insecure (which is more accurate than "trusted"). the accepted answer about OpenSSL is correct

Comment: This is useful when behind a MITM corporate proxy.

Answer (score 11):

One note on the above answers: it is no longer sufficient to add just pypi.python.org to the trusted-hosts in the case where you are behind an HTTPS-intercepting proxy (we have zScaler).

I currently have the following in my pip.ini:

```
trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

Running `pip -v install pkg` will give you some hints as to which hosts might need to be added.

Comment: If pip.ini does not exist, you have to also create the [global] section, then put in the "trusted-host = ..." line.

Comment: You can also supply multiple `--trusted-host` arguments to your `pip install`.

Comment: it should be noted that this is a VERY RISKY IDEA! this disables HTTPS certificate validation, and allows a man in the middle to install ARBITRARY CODE. curl calls this option --insecure (which is more accurate than "trusted"). the accepted answer about OpenSSL is correct

Answer (score 7):

Something to try --- tell python to not use https with the index directive and a http:// address (not https://)

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  Scrapy
```

You may be behind a corporate firewall and Ive have experiences where even the above failed, though Im not going to pretend like I know enough about firewalls or SSL to understand why. In that case the only way I was able to get around that was to get a certificate file and pass it to python. See [kenorb’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39124754/766330) here for details.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using python3, you can try this too:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Scrapy --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
```

Comment: Worked for me on Mac

Answer (score 3):

```
 pip3 install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <app>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `Scrapy` fails because installing `Twisted` fails, which fails because `incremental` fails.  Running `pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --upgrade incremental` fixed this for me.

Answer (score 1):

If adding pypi.python.org as a trusted host does not work, you try adding files.pythonhosted.org. For example

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows 10 / search the drive you have installed the conda or it should be in C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\pipright with your mouse right click and select edit with notepad leave the [global] and replace what ever you have in there with blow code, Ctrl+s and rerun the code. it should work.

```
trusted-host = pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the solution. In my case the file %appdata%\pip\pip.ini was not present. I created it manually with this content:

```
[global]
trusted-host = pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.org pypi.io
```

Comment: In my case it needed to be created here: `C:\Users\MY-USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pip.ini`

Answer (score 1):

The following command worked for me (install a package using pip)

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `sudo apt-get upgrade` to get the latest packages. It fixed the issue on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are also using pypi.org now.  I added the following to %appdata%\pip\pip.ini and was able to download my packages from behind an HTTPS-intercepting proxy:

`trusted-host = pypi.python.org files.pythonhosted.org pypi.org`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I was trying to install `mysqlclient` for my Django project.

In my case the **system date/time** wasn't up-to date (Windows 8). That's causing the error. So, updated my system date time and ran the command `pip install mysqlclient` again. And it did the work.

Hope this would be helpful for those people who're executing all the commands out there (suggesting in other answers) without checking their system date/time.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty unique case here, but having Fiddler running (not even targeting the same process) gave me the same SSL errors. Running pip install with `--verbose` showed an error with Fiddler, closing Fiddler immediately fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that nobody came up with this in so many years?

I debugged a Python 2 legacy setup and ran into the same error, just with some other package:

> Download error on http://www.pylonshq.com/download/: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- Some packages may not be found!
> Not found: ['http://www.pylonshq.com/download/', and here were also my internal server links with legacy packages in the list]
> ...
> Couldn't find index page for 'PasteDeploy' (maybe misspelled?)
> No local packages or download links found for PasteDeploy
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "setup.py", line 50, in 
> """,
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
> _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 239, in **init**
> self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 264, in fetch_build_eggs
> replace_conflicting=True
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 620, in resolve
> dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 858, in best_match
> return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 870, in obtain
> return installer(requirement)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 314, in fetch_build_egg
> return cmd.easy_install(req)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 616, in easy_install
> return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 646, in install_item
> dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 834, in install_eggs
> return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1040, in build_and_install
> self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1028, in run_setup
> raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('PasteDeploy')

Clearly, that download website is offline, and easy_install and eggs are deprecated. But you can still learn from this, I guess: you need to put the needed package in the `setup_requires=[]` list, not in the `install_requires=[]`, and only then, it found the internal packages server with the legacy packages (you can also take an open packages server here).

The package was at

```py
install_requires=["PasteDeploy>=1.0.0", ...],
```

but *setuptools* needed the entry instead at:

```py
setup_requires=["PasteDeploy>=1.0.0, ...],
```

For some packages, it is not enough to put them in the `install_requires=[]` list since they are already needed during the *setuptools* setup which is needed before the install.

(Only setuptools should not be in there, see [Should setuptools be in the setup_requires entry of setup.cfg files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58530707/11154841)).