# cannot install jupyter using pip3

Tags: python, jupyter

> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/jupyter/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) - skipping

I am using a Windows 7 machine, Python 3.6 version and pip version is 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Using what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509902/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-using-pip-to-install-packages) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25981703/pip-install-fails-with-connection-error-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certi):

```
pip install --index-url=http://pypi.python.org/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.python.org  jupyter
```

Comment: Thanks, I found the issue. There was a network issue which was blocking me to install jupyter stack as i was at  my work place.