# how to fix distutils.errors.DistutilsError on py2app?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, py2app

I recently tried to use py2app and I have a simple app named test.py. everything is fine, until I type 'python3 setup.py py2app'. here is the error message:

> Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/py2app/: [SSL:
>   CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) --
>   Some packages may not be found! Couldn't find index page for 'py2app'
>   (maybe misspelled?) Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/:
>   [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed
>   (_ssl.c:748) -- Some packages may not be found! No local packages or
>   working download links found for py2app Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File "setup.py", line 18, in 
>       setup_requires=['py2app'],   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py",
>   line 108, in setup
>       _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
>   line 315, in **init**
>       self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
>   line 361, in fetch_build_eggs
>       replace_conflicting=True,   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 850, in resolve
>       dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 1122, in best_match
>       return self.obtain(req, installer)   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/**init**.py",
>   line 1134, in obtain
>       return installer(requirement)   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py",
>   line 429, in fetch_build_egg
>       return cmd.easy_install(req)   File "/Users/dariushmazlumi/Desktop/test/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py",
>   line 659, in easy_install
>       raise DistutilsError(msg) distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('py2app')

I'm using python3.6 on macOS sierra.

Comment: Checkout this question it might have your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509902/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-using-pip-to-install-packages

Comment: thank's @WombatPM; there are three answers. first only work's, but it doesn't solve my problem(I can install, but some things like py2app doesn't work!), second answer was 'certifi'. I installed but it doesn't work. I didn't try the third one, but also it will not solve my problem, maybe it will just work, like first one.

Comment: also, thank you @BillBEGUERADJ for your edits

Comment: Thanks for that link @WombatPM , doing `pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org py2app` in my virtualenv solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reported python bug that was caused by Apple no longer installing open SSL.  See this [discussion](https://bugs.python.org/issue28150).

Comment: thanks @WombatPM! how can I run /Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command according to https://bugs.python.org/issue28150?

Comment: hello?@WombatPM?

Comment: I ran it by sudo ../../Applications/Python 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command! let my try py2app and pip3!

Comment: maybe rebooting!

Comment: ): its not working! still that error.

Comment: I found out something, this error message is because setup tools in setup.py, it want to use easy_install, to install something, and certificate error happens.

Comment: it was py2app. but even when I install py2app in my virtual environment, an other error happens. I ran something else in my test.app (via terminal): no module named tkinter ): (I have it installed in my mac)

Answer (score 0):

after a week trying to fix my problem, I found out why my py2app, pip, and ... are not working. it is my antivirus(Kaspersky) problem. today, when opening google.com, I understand that I had a problem opening any page. I had same problem on other browsers. I read that error message in safari. Kaspersky issued all certificates!(including pip,py2app ...) I fixed it by disabling: kaspersky internet security > preference > protection > check secure connections(https). thanks everyone for their help.