# how to fix 'CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED' error on mac?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ssl, pip

recently, I'm having a problem with my pip I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45986031/how-can-i-fix-pips-certificate-error), and it also effected my easy_install and my py2app. according to answer I get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985535/how-to-fix-distutils-errors-distutilserror-on-py2app), I tried 'Install Certificates.command' last night. now, my pip is working! but my easy_install, pip3, easy_install3 and py2app still don't work with this error(`pip3 install <anymodule>`):

> Collecting anymodule
>
> Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/anymodule/: There was a
>
> problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
>
> certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748) - skipping
>
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anymodule (from
>
> versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for anymodule

and I tried almost anything! I'm using python2 and 3 on a macOS sierra. I appreciate your help very very much!(;

update:sudo easy_install  is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a week trying to fix my problem, I found out why my py2app, pip, and ... are not working. it is my antivirus(Kaspersky) problem. today, when opening google.com, I understand that I had a problem opening any page. I had same problem on other browsers. I read that error message in safari. Kaspersky issued all certificates!(including pip,py2app ...) I fixed it by disabling: kaspersky internet security > preference > protection > check secure connections(https).