# Is setuptools always installed in Python by default?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

Is `setuptools` always installed with Python?

I would like to invoke `setuptools` at runtime outside of a `setup.py` script.

In other words, should I include `setuptools` inside my package's `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`'s `install_requires` list?

---

**Background**

I have noticed when creating a new virtual environment (with Python 3.7.9) that both `pip` and `setuptools` are installed by default:

```
python -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip list

Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        20.1.1
setuptools 47.1.0
```

This is documented here: [Creating Virtual Environments](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments):

> venv is available by default in Python 3.3 and later, and installs pip and setuptools into created virtual environments in Python 3.4 and later.

Even in a vanilla version of Python 3.7.6 (installed via [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)), the packages installed by default are both `pip` and `setuptools`.

---

**Research**

[Should setuptools be included in setup_requires in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521386/should-setuptools-be-included-in-setup-requires-in-python)

Informs that `setuptools` should not be included in `setup_requires`, but does not talk about it being included in package requirements for runtime use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR

Formally, No. Usually, Yes.

the setuptools is not part of the python vanilla codebase, hence not a [vanilla modules](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html#cap-s).

python.org installers or mac homebrew will install it for you, but if someone compile the python by himself or install it on some linux distribution he may not get it and will need to [install it by himself](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/).

Comment: So @LiorCohen do you think I should include `setuptools` inside a `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`'s `install_requires`?

Comment: Yes for requirements.txt. because this is a dependency. No for setup.py because if you are able to run it, it means you already have setuptools.

Comment: Being able to run `setup.py` doesn't quite mean you already have `setuptools`. It's possible (though not recommended) to use `distutils` instead of `setuptools`.

Comment: correct, I assume the setup.py import the setup function from setuptools

Comment: FWIF I noticed on Arch linux it was not installed.