# Is there a way to install "pystan" & "fbprophet". I getting errors while installing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pystan, facebook-prophet

I tried installing via pip and conda, both ways failed. Anybody know how to overcome this problem.

[image: Pystan installation error]

Comment: I highly suggest you to use   python through anaconda environment (download it from here https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual)  and  then open the anaconda prompt and run  conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet in a super easy way. I also had problem with installing fbprophet. Regarding pystan, I never tried to install.

Comment: @Tom, I tried as you say, but got other errors. Pasting below

Comment: (base) C:\Users\srikrishnamupalaneni>conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64'



(base) C:\Users\srikrishnamupalaneni>

Comment: I don't know where that error could be coming from . Did you try to install anaconda again? Try to create a new anaconda environment and install with  conda install -c conda-forge fbprophet ? Idk ,I've installed that way in many computers with windows and never failed hahah.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with SSL rather than a problem specific to this package. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42509902/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-using-pip-to-install-packages for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you All for responding, I got the problem solved.
Solution - There is a Firewall installed on my laptop by my company. It is blocking me from installing some packages.